# Is this spot significant in Reflecting Cave?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

If you're not paying attention, there is a short hidden path in the Reflecting Cave that leads to a dead end. In this path you can find the HM for Gyro Ball, but it's at the dead end that has me curious. What is the significance of this area? If you bring a certain Pokemon or item to this spot, does something happen? It's the only area of the cave that I saw a big spot of light.

[image: Reflecting Cave]

Comment: Is this dead end path on the third basement level?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yes I believe so, it's shortly before you get to the exit of the cave.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This dead end is the location of Alakazam's Mega Evolution stone. That is one of the stones that you can only find between 8 and 9 PM after your Mega Ring has been upgraded in the post-game.